# Why does "List<T>.Insert(index, T)" add to end of list instead of index?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a timer with the tick function:

```
    void CollisionTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int j;
        angle += 10;
        angle %= 360;

        int i = angle / 10 - 1;
        if (i < 0)
            j = 0;
        else
            j =i % 35;

        ObstaclePoints.Insert(j, getPoint(angle));
    }
```

The desired effect is the point list 'ObstaclePoints' gets 36 points as j iterates between 0-35.

The problem i get is after the first 36 ticks and j goes back to 0, the list keeps getting added to and i get more than 36 points in my list. (i.e. after another 36 ticks i get 72 points in my list, instead of the first 36 being overwritten).

Why does this happen and how can i fix this?

Comment: What language is this? It looks like it would be [tag:c++] but i don't see that tag.

Comment: Wasn't C either, downvoted.

Comment: @iharob - It's C#, the tag is there.

Comment: Its C#.. im using WPF in visual studio

Comment: An insert will not overwrite an existing item in the list, it will add a new item at position x.

Comment: What is `i`, what is `j`?  My brain is frazzled!

Comment: @DarrenYoung - Yes writing readable code is an art.

Comment: @martinstoeckli It is, but it's generally something that comes with experience so you can't be too tough :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List.Insert` does not overwrite the item at the specified index, but does insert one at this position. Use an array `ObstaclePoints[35]` instead an adress it as the following code shows:

```
ObstaclePoints[j] = getPoint(angle);
```

Comment: This would also work with a List. It doesn't *have* to be an array.

Comment: @Clemens In addition, remember to `Add` the items to the list before trying to access them.

Comment: @Clemens OK, but if the Count of the list will be constant, I do prefer an array. Using a list, you have to add the items first before accessing the, as mentioned by Kyle.